# Turn figure around a given point on the angle

Tags: java, graphics2d

I draw an oval `g.fillOval (0, 0, 100, 40)`; How to turn it from the center of the figure at any angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Graphics2D`, you could do:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
g2.rotate(angle, 51, 21);
```

Comment: I use Graphics g. May be I need use Graphics2D?